# What are gateways and gateway tokens?

Tags: token

I recently paid for a 'proof of human' token (solving a Captcha) from [Civic](https://civic.me/). It's stored as a ['gateway token' with 'gatekeepers' in my wallet](https://explorer.identity.com/address/GcXHYtQg4deGssAYbqdsb3zKBc58j6LKBJA3A9gsQ9Fo/domains). I've searched for 'gateway token' and 'gatekeeper' but not been able to find much documentation on these topics.

**What are gateway tokens and gatekeepers?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gateway token is a token used to control access to dApps.

On-chain applications require users to present a Gateway Token, which proves that they have been verified by a Gateway Provider to use the dApp. This token is tied to their wallet and is non-transferable.

[image: solana-gateway components]

Gateway tokens are issued by gatekeepers. A cluster of gatekeepers with similar rules for issuing gateway tokens are defined as a Gatekeeper Network.

The on-chain program chooses a gatekeeper network to trust, by adding its public key to a program account.

This library then validates that gateway tokens are issued by gatekeepers in this network and are valid.

More info available through the 'solana-gateway' docs: https://crates.io/crates/solana-gateway